# Why does my Android app icon display different in different Android device?how to keep it same?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, icons, android-studio-2.2

I have set the icon resource in AndroidManifest.xml file like this

...

(because the project was established in eclipse before,then move to Android Studio,I do not know if the problem depend on IDE or others.and drawable-hdpi,drwable-mdpi,drawable-w720dp,drawable-xhdpi have the same icon,just for fit different dpi of Android device)

I did this,then I tested my app on Android 4.4,it display another icon,the icon not exist in the project at all,then I tested it in Android 5.1,the same icon display in it,finally I tested it in Android 6.0,it become normal,I am very confused why it do not display the icon I want in some other Android device

and later I found there are 5 different icon display in different Android device,maybe more,I do not know how to solve it...

I tried to set the same icon in the LAUNCHER Acticity,but it still did not work...rebuid the project,and all kinds of solution I have tried,it also still did not work...

who can help me ...

Comment: there should be different pixel icon in every folder(hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi), see the android documention

Comment: but why it display unexist icons in other Android device,I want to know where are they from...

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
Check this doc

Comment: http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/

Answer (score 0):

Check the Android documentation. You should create different icons in different folders. (hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi.)
Each folder will be use with the relevant screen.

Comment: Should I delete build files to rebuild when I created the five types images?

Answer (score 0):

Is it a Phonegap/Cordova App? Then have a look in the /res/icon/iOs/ folder. replace the icons there with yours. sometimes Cordova uses iOs icons for android builds.

Comment: Thank you,it is a Android app,developed in Android Studio.